# VB.NET : How to print the checkbox text and the checkbox state

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, printing

I new in VB.net programming 
I am asking if there is a way to print the checkbox itself including the box beside the text and the text itself.Is it possible to print it?If so ,can you share some code?

Comment: Print as in "on paper, out of the printer", or print as in "give some kind of feedback through the console" ?

Comment: I tried printing the checkbox using PrintDocument.if i click the print button i like it both the text and the box of the checkbox to be print" on the paper".

Comment: You can print several things, including a form, but a lone control is a weird demand. I thus infer that I must be missing something.